# Como generar un sistema que lleve el marcador de un juego en python

Tags: python

Buenas soy muy novato en programación y quisiera saber como podría hacer para generar un marcador que me lleve la cuenta de los puntos obtenidos, es decir en el código que se adjunta es un programa muy sencillo en el que si insertas un 1 te da 100 ptos y si insertas un 2 te da 0 ptos y se reinicia el programa.
Entonces mi problema es que no se como hacer para almacenar la variable de los puntos que me de para que cuando se reinicie el programa los sume a los nuevos puntos que se obtengan y me lo de en la terminal.
Adjunto el código a continuación:

```
def introduccion():
    print("hola que tal")

def elige():
    elige=int(input("introduce un numero: "))
    if elige == 1:
      print("+100ptos")
    elif elige == 2:
      print("0pts")

def a():
   volver=input("introduce si quieres volveer: ")
    while volver=="si" or volver=="s":
       volver=0
       introduccion()
       elige()
       a()

introduccion()
elige()
a()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo basta con definir una variable global `puntos` y en la función `elige()` que modifica la variable invocarla como global.

```
puntos = 0

def elige():
    global puntos

    #...
```

De esta manera el valor de `puntos` se mantendrá hasta el final del programa.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo mejor es que utilices una clase en estos casos, de esta forma podrás almacenar el resultado en un atributo dentro de ella, en este caso, la puntuación.

Te dejaré el código lo más simple posible (se puede refactorizar y optimizar mucho más):

Código:

```
import sys

class Juego:

    puntuacion = 0

    def imprimirMensaje(self, mensaje):
        print(mensaje)

    def introducirNumero(self):
        numero = int(input("Introduce un número: "))
        if numero == 1:
            self.puntuacion += 100
            self.imprimirMensaje("+100 Pts.")
        elif numero == 2:
            self.imprimirMensaje("0 Pts.")

    def preguntar(self):
        pregunta = input("Deseas volver? ")
        while pregunta != 'no':
            self.introducirNumero()
            self.preguntar()
        else:
            self.imprimirMensaje("Tu puntuación es: "+str(self.puntuacion))
            sys.exit()

nuevo_juego = Juego()
nuevo_juego.preguntar()
```

Ejecución:

```
Deseas volver? si
Introduce un número: 1
+100 Pts.
Deseas volver? si
Introduce un número: 1
+100 Pts.
Deseas volver? si
Introduce un número: 0
Deseas volver? no
Tu puntuación es: 200
```